# Only external drive appears when attempting to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 from a USB drive onto a laptop already running Windows 10. I don't want to dual-boot, I would like to install Ubuntu and erase/reformat the hard drive. I have no trouble booting from the USB drive and starting on the install. I was hoping to come across a menu like the below
[image]
from [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-drive-management). Instead, I am getting this menu
[image]
which only allows me to install to the external drive. Additionally, trying to install to this USB drive doesn't even work, failing because "no root file system is defined." The device for boot loader installation dropdown doesn't have the main hard drive as an option. How can I install Ubuntu to the main disk and remove Windows? Thanks for any help.

Comment: @user535733 Pressing 'back' any amount doesn't solve this. While I've tried a number of different settings, all (including the default options) lead to this point. The menu before this one has only the normal/minimal, download updates, and third-party software options.

Comment: Did you properly shut down Windows and disable Windows FastBoot? Are the sizes of your disk(s) approximately correct? Or is a disk missing for the list?

Comment: If the disk is missing then likely the default drive settings in UEFI is some incompatible mode like "RAID" or Intel RST. Change it to AHCI and try again. But before all of this make sure the UEFI is updated so keep Windows for that action at least as some manufacturers publish updates as Windows executables only.

Comment: @ChanganAuto That was exactly the problem. Thank you both for your help. If anyone else comes across this, switching to AHCI might solve the issue (even if the current is 'disabled' or something else other than RST).

Comment: @ChanganAuto it will be very useful to turn your comment into an answer